# How to find maximum and minimum value of multivariable function on this set?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

Given some function $f = x + 2y + 3z$ on the set which is defined as:

$\begin{cases} 
x \geq 0\\
y \geq 0\\
x + y \leq 3\\
x + y \leq z\\
3x + 3y \geq z
\end{cases}$

As I understood, such restriction represents the area between two planes and there is a some figure that moves up and down intersecting the area.

My depicting skills are bad and neither I can apply Lagrange multipliers or any other technique here.

So how do I find the minimum and maximum value of $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have found that $$f(x,y,z)\le 33$$ and the equal sign holds for $$x=0,y=3,z=9$$

Comment: I got to the point where $f \leq 30 + y$. So, how you derived $y \leq 3$?

Comment: since we have $$x+y\le 3$$ we get for $y=3$ $x\le 0$ this is only possible for $x=0$

Comment: Ah, yeah, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was really an elegant solution. I didn't think about estimation at all!

Comment: thank you for the flowers, it is nice that i could help you!